# ASP.NET MVC ModelBindingContext issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to model `bindingcontext` and can't understand why I keep getting `null` on result

As far as I understand I need to implement `IUnvalidatedValueProvider` in order to turn off validation (as users are posting html).

```
public class AccountFormBinder : IModelBinder 
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        //Cast the value provider to an IUnvalidatedValueProvider, which allows to skip validation
        IUnvalidatedValueProvider provider = bindingContext.ValueProvider as IUnvalidatedValueProvider;
        var result = provider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName,true);
        return result.AttemptedValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in the end

```
HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
var re = request.Unvalidated("CMessage");
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you just want to allow HTML to be posted? You don't need a custom modelbinder for that. Just add `[AllowHtml]` to whatever properties should allow HTML containing post values:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    ...
    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.Html)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: FYI I have a mixture of partial views on the page so I have to use a custom model binder

Comment: No, you don't. There's other ways to handle that such as child actions or form prefixes.